# What does Quinlan mean by "the confidence limits for the binomial distribution"?

Tags: binomial-distribution, data-mining

My classmates and I are trying to figure out what J. Ross Quinlan means on page 41 of *C4.5: Programs for Machine Learning*. He says:

> The probability of error cannot be determined easily, but has itself a (posterior) probability distribution that is usually summarized by a pair of confidence limits. For a given confidence level *CF*, the upper limit on this probability can be found from the confidence limits for the binomial distribution; this upper limit is here written $U_{CF}(E, N)$.

Quinlan gives a few examples:

> $U_{25\%}(0, 6) = 0.206$

My class textbook, *Data Mining Concepts, Models, Methods, and Algorithms* by Mehmed Kantardzic gives slightly more detail, but not enough:

> C4.5 follows the *postpruning* approach, but it uses a specific technique to estimate the predicted error rate. This method is called *pessimistic pruning*. For every node in a tree, the estimation of the upper confidence limit $U_{cf}$ is computed using the statistical tables for binomial distribution (given in most textbooks on statistics). Parameter $U_{cf}$ is a function of $|T_i|$ and $E$ for a given node. C4.5 uses the default confidence level of 25% and compares $U_{25\%}(|T_i|/E)$ for a given node $T_i$ with a weighted confidence of its leaves.

Kantardzic provides a few more examples of this function:

> $U_{25\%}(6,0) = 0.206, U_{25\%}(9,0) = 0.143, U_{25\%}(1,0) = 0.750$

At least [one other person on the Internet](https://community.rapidminer.com/discussion/14724/calculate-errors-for-leaf-in-a-decision-tree-c4-5) has the same question.

I have been unable to find these values in the [binomial probability distribution](https://www.sjsu.edu/people/saul.cohn/courses/stats/s0/BinomialProbabTable.pdf) ${n \choose r}  p^r q^{n-r}$.

What does this syntax mean, and where do I compute this function (ideally in R or Julia)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally answered my own question. Apparently this is the Clopper-Pearson Confidence Interval. You the Binomial Confidence Interval calculator at https://statpages.info/confint.html. First, enter $25$ for `% Area in Upper Tail` and $0$ for `% Area in Lower Tail`.

### R

You can compute this in R using the [`GenBinomApps`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GenBinomApps/index.html) package.

```
> install.packages('GenBinomApps')
Warning: package 'GenBinomApps' is in use and will not be installed
> library(GenBinomApps)
> clopper.pearson.ci(0, 6, alpha = .25, CI = "upper")
 Confidence.Interval Lower.limit Upper.limit alpha
               upper           0   0.2062995  0.25
> clopper.pearson.ci(0, 9, alpha = .25, CI = "upper")
 Confidence.Interval Lower.limit Upper.limit alpha
               upper           0    0.142756  0.25
> clopper.pearson.ci(0, 1, alpha = .25, CI = "upper")
 Confidence.Interval Lower.limit Upper.limit alpha
               upper           0        0.75  0.25
> clopper.pearson.ci(1, 16, alpha = .25, CI = "upper")
 Confidence.Interval Lower.limit Upper.limit alpha
               upper           0   0.1596107  0.25
```

### Julia

Julia's [`HypothesisTests.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/HypothesisTests.jl) package will not accept such a low level. I have not found a way to compute $U_{25\%}(n, x)$ in Julia yet, but I have not tried very hard either.

```
julia> using StatsKit

julia> confint(BinomialTest(0, 6); level = .25, tail = :right)
ERROR: ArgumentError: coverage level 0.25 not in range (0.5, 1)
Stacktrace:
 [1] check_level
   @ C:\Users\wjhol\.julia\packages\HypothesisTests\V7PST\src\HypothesisTests.jl:96 [inlined]
 [2] confint(x::BinomialTest; level::Float64, tail::Symbol, method::Symbol)
   @ HypothesisTests C:\Users\wjhol\.julia\packages\HypothesisTests\V7PST\src\binomial.jl:104
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[2]:1
```

### Python

[This discussion on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059011/is-there-any-python-function-library-for-calculate-binomial-confidence-intervals) discusses some ways to get this CI in Python.